# Проблема с HTTPS на локальном прокси сервере

Tags: c#, proxy, ssl

Имеется программа со встроенным *Firefox: xulrunner* под управлением *GeckoFX 33*.

Ввиду того, что для работы необходимо соединение *FF* через *socks* с авторизацией, а *socks* с авторизацией *GeckoFX* не поддерживает (насколько я понял, *xulrunner* не даёт для этого соответствующего интерфейса), я решил организовать соединение через локальный прокси-сервер, через который *FF* работал бы стандартными встроенными средствами, а дальше я планировал организовать соединения через *socks*.

Вот код сервера, который запускается в отдельном потоке и слушает порт:

```
class ProxyService
{
    public static void RunServer()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Запускаем сервер.");
        TcpListener myTCP = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 7777);
        myTCP.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            //Thread.Sleep(20);
            // смотрим, есть запрос или нет
            if (myTCP.Pending())
            {
                // запрос есть
                using (Socket myClient = myTCP.AcceptSocket())
                {
                    // соединяемся
                    if (myClient.Connected)
                    {
                        // получаем тело запроса
                        byte[] httpRequest = ReadToEnd(myClient);
                        // ищем хост и порт
                        Regex myReg = new Regex(@"Host: (((?<host>.+?):(?<port>\d+?))|(?<host>.+?))\s+", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                        Match m = myReg.Match(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(httpRequest));
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\nИсходящий запрос программы: \n" + System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(httpRequest));
                        string host = m.Groups["host"].Value;
                        int port = 0;
                        // если порта нет, то используем 80 по умолчанию
                        if (!int.TryParse(m.Groups["port"].Value, out port)) { port = 80; }
                        Console.WriteLine("Port: " + port + "\n");

                        // получаем апишник по хосту
                        if(host == "")
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        IPHostEntry myIPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(host);

                        // создаем точку доступа
                        IPEndPoint myIPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(myIPHostEntry.AddressList[0], port);

                        // создаем сокет и передаем ему запрос
                        using (Socket myRerouting = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
                        {
                            myRerouting.Connect(myIPEndPoint);
                            if (myRerouting.Send(httpRequest, httpRequest.Length, SocketFlags.None) != httpRequest.Length)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("При отправке данных удаленному серверу произошла ошибка...");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // получаем ответ
                                byte[] httpResponse = ReadToEnd(myRerouting);
                                string resp = (Encoding.ASCII.GetString(httpResponse).Length > 1010) ? Encoding.ASCII.GetString(httpResponse).Remove(1000) : Encoding.ASCII.GetString(httpResponse);
                                Console.WriteLine("Ответ сайта:\n" + resp);
                                // передаем ответ обратно клиенту
                                if (httpResponse != null && httpResponse.Length > 0)
                                {
                                    myClient.Send(httpResponse, httpResponse.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static byte[] ReadToEnd(Socket mySocket)
    {
        byte[] b = new byte[mySocket.ReceiveBufferSize];
        int len = 0;
        using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
        {
            while (mySocket.Poll(1000000, SelectMode.SelectRead) && (len = mySocket.Receive(b, mySocket.ReceiveBufferSize, SocketFlags.None)) > 0)
            {
                m.Write(b, 0, len);
            }
            return m.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Сайты через *HTTP* открываются нормально, а через *HTTPS* не открываются, выскакивает ошибка:

> site.ru could not be found. Please check the name and try again.

В консоль вывожу диалог программы и сайта:

```
Исходящий запрос программы: 

CONNECT site.ru:443 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive
Host: site.ru:443

Ответ сайта:

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: Apache
Date: Thu, 16 Jul 2015 16:30:40 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 189
Connection: close

<html>
<head><title>500 Internal Server Error</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1></center>
<hr><center> Apache </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Кто-нибудь знает, как с этим бороться?

Answer (score 1):

Первый запрос, который идёт к прокси - это `CONNECT`. Если коротко - клиент (браузер) просит прокси установить TCP коннекшен "за него" (немного подробностей например [тут (англ)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_tunnel#HTTP_CONNECT_tunneling)). Вы форвардите этот запрос своему сайту, который не является прокси и не может обработать запрос `CONNECT`, и возвращает вам `500 Internal Server Error`.

Как поправить - отдельно обрабатывать `CONNECT`, а в остальном всё должно заработать.